# How to use 仿佛 properly?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

To give context, this is the sentence:

> 永远不能忘记的是北京，因为我在那里住的太久了，仿佛树生了根一样。

I am not sure how to render the last bit. I'm guessing it's saying:

1. As if I am a tree, the roots are the same as my life, sown in from
   birth;
2. I'm the same as a growing tree and its roots.

Not sure if I'm picking out the right things, I'm reading 仿佛 and 一样 as separate items, or does the sentence construction 仿佛...一样 have a meaning of some kind?

If so, how to use it, what is the difference between saying just 仿佛，or using 仿佛...一样?

Comment: 仿佛...一样 a sentence pattern, but 一样 is optional，we can also use 仿佛...一般.

Comment: `仿佛` is seldom used in daily conversation. But if you are writing an essay it's OK to use it.

Comment: Accidentally linked to this, I shall point that 彷彿 is the orthography, and 仿佛 is discouraged. [教育部辭典](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?ccd=04bJSh&o=e0&sec1=1&op=sid=%22Z00000036481%22.&v=-2)

Answer (score 2):

仿佛:    seem; as if ; just like

```
Example1 : 她工作努力，仿佛不知疲倦似的。 She works hard as if she never knew fatigue .
Example2 : 无论我提议什么事，她仿佛都不愿干。She doesn't seem to want to do anything i suggest.
Example3 : 她她如此美丽，仿佛就像个天使。 She so beautiful just like an angel.
```

Answer (score 2):

@daniel and @user3835327 have provided enough information on the usage of 仿佛. Your understanding of the sentence doesn't seem to be on spot. It says:

> ...I have been living there for too long, just like a tree rooted to
>   this land (so that we became inseparable).

Answer (score 0):

仿佛 is that you feels like, but it's not true;
一样 is that actually existed and the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple ways to use 仿佛, as well as meaning:
仿佛 = `as if`, `seem` (as provided by user3835327)

仿佛...一样 means `seems like`, for example:
仿佛树生了根一样 - Seems like the tree has rooted there.

Therefore 仿佛 and 一样 can be used separately, while together they forms a sentence structure.